# Recursively replace value for each occurrence of a specific key within multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, recursion, multidimensional-array

I have an array that can vary in how many arrays deep there are, for example:

```
array(
  'one' => array(
     array(
        'something' => 'value'
     ),
     array(
        'something2' => 'value2'
     ),
     'another' => 'anothervalue'
  ),
  'two' =>  array(
     array(
        'something' => 'value'
     ),
     array(
        'something2' => 'value2'
     ),
     'another' => 'anothervalue'
  )
)
```

Now, let's say I want to replace everything with the key 'something'.

Would I need to use a recursive function to iterate through the array? or is there a better way?

Comment: I think that recursion is the best way.

Comment: With what do you want to replace it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Have a look at [`array_walk_recursive`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php). It may be quite handy in a situation like this.

Here's an example using array_walk_recursive:

```
$arr = array(
      'one' => array(
            array('something' => 'value'),
            array('something2' => 'value2'),
            'another' => 'anothervalue'
            ),
      'two' =>  array(
            array('something' => 'value'),
            array('something2' => 'value2'),
            'another' => 'anothervalue'
            )
       );

function update_something(&$item, $key)
{
    if($key == 'something')
        $item = 'newValue';
}

array_walk_recursive($arr, 'update_something');
```

If used inside a class the callback method have to add the object along with the function. This is achieved with an array:

```
array_walk_recursive($arr, array($this, 'update_something'));
```

Comment: Can this be done inside a class? I have to call my functions using $this->functionName

Comment: That should not be a problem :) Here's an example `array_walk_recursive($arr, array($this, 'update_something'));`

Comment: `array_walk_recursive($arr, [__CLASS__,'update_something']);`
It's just aesthetic preferences :))

Answer (score 2):

This is a function that you can either be used as a global function or you just put it into a class:

```
/**
 * replace any value in $array specified by $key with $value
 *
 * @return array array with replaced values
 */
function replace_recursive(Array $array, $key, $value)
{
    array_walk_recursive($array, function(&$v, $k) use ($key, $value)
        {$k == $key && $v = $value;});
    return $array;
}

# usage:
$array = replace_recursive($array, 'something', 'replaced');
```

It's also making use of `array_walk_recursive` but encapsulated. The key and the value can be specified as function parameters and not hardencoded in some callback, so it's more flexible.