# Search and replace value of a key in an array in PHP

Tags: php

Let's say I have an array like this:

```
    $myArray = array( 
    'a' => 'alpha',
    'b' => array(
        'Z' => 'zulu' )
    );
```

I'd like to search for the key 'Z' and replace its value.

I've tried iterators, foreach loops, etc but no luck.

*** Amended syntax.

Comment: That isn't PHP array syntax. That is a cross between Ruby hash syntax with a PHP `array` keyword.  Please post valid PHP so we can fully understand your intent.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski does it look better? I need to find the key 'Z' which is in an array within an array and replace its value. Many thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7801463/replace-certain-items-within-multidimensional-array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a reference to array_walk_recursive:

```
   $myArray = array( 
    'a' => 'alpha',
    'b' => array(
        'Z' => 'zulu' )
    );

$newvalue = 'zebra';

array_walk_recursive($myArray, function(&$value, $key) use($newvalue){
    if($key=='Z'){
        $value = $newvalue;
    }
});

print_r($myArray);
```

example: http://codepad.viper-7.com/ajsYEn

Comment: @L4zl0w Oops, forgot to put $newvalue in scope, please see my edit

Comment: This seems to be the correct answer as it didn't work without passing in the new value with use(). Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

$myArray = array(
    'a' => 'alpha',
    'b' => array (
        'Z' => 'zulu' 
    ),
);


foreach($myArray as $key => $value) {
    if (is_array($value)) {
        foreach($value as $k => $v) {
            if ($k == 'Z')
            {
                //do something
                $myArray[$key]['newKey'] = $v;
                unset($myArray[$key][$k]);
            }
        }
    }
}

print_r($myArray);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [a] => alpha
    [b] => Array
        (
            [newKey] => zulu
        )

)
```

Comment: I can see the logic behind the second foreach but this example doesn't tell me how to change the value of the key 'Z'. Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use `array_walk_recursive` and pass by reference:

```
array_walk_recursive($myArray, function(&$item, $key) {
   if ($key == 'Z') $item = "hi";
});
```

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ad750cbb5b30b87f9e6068ba15420cf924ed5a7b

Comment: yes it does - you can see in the link I posted.  If it's not working in your code then we need to see more, because there is something else happening.